# Routing Form POST request from Visualforce Page through Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, httprequest, ip

I am making a form post request from page and hence the request is taking user's IP address into consideration. Is there any way to continue having a form POST and provide a dummy URL in action tag which will in turn hit Salesforce internal URL and make a call from server so that request goes from Salesforce trusted IPs.

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://website.com/action.php" method="POST" target="abcd">
  <input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="Sam" />
  <input type="hidden" name="city" value="NYC;" />
  <input onclick="window.location.href = abcd type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

Is something like that possible?

Comment: Yes - by using a standard or custom controller. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/visualforce_fundamentals

Comment: Won't that be considered as server call? Will the response come in similar format as form POST?

Comment: Your VF page would call the controller, the controller would have to make a callout. (Thus, it'd have to be a custom controller. Standard controllers won't call out). Only then the source IP will be that of the Salesforce "server". See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts for an example of a callout.